# Adding a textView

Tags: java, android, listview

Just started with android development, I decided to work the api demos, trying to add little features, modifying them, etc.

I'm currently on List8 and I want to add a textView to it, like a little description of the photos on each ListView row. So, how do I do that keeping the main.xml layout, I tried "drawing" a TextView object in `public View getView()`But they won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("test");
view.addView(textView);
```

Comment: Am i supposed to add that in PhotoAdapterClass ?

Comment: You're supposed to do it in Activity.